# Application does not arrive in Programs and Features after installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.6, wix-extension, wixlib

I have made an installer for website application. It is built successfully, and has entries in registry and IIS. But it was not registered in the Programs and Features for uninstall. I have to manually remove from registry and IIS. What's that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you created a MSI installer, and don't see entry in the "Programs and Features", it means that you enabled the SYSTEMCOMPONENT property (which hides your app there). 

 
To check it, go to the registry and find there you application by GUID:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{YOUR_GUID}` and look for `SystemComponent` key with value `1`. If it exists than problem can be solved by disabling or setting this property to value `0` in WiX.

Comment: Thanks Igor...very important information you gave me. You know sometime it was also happen vise verse. I mean, sometime it installed successfully and register into the IIS and Programs and Features, but not registered in registry. Why it is behave differently in different time?

Comment: Actually, if you use x64 version OS, and install the x86 application, Windows Installer writes registry (installation information for "Programs and Features") to 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Comment: Oho...happen exactly what I said you...This time it entry in Programs and Features an IIS but not in Registry..and I am testing x64 version OS and installing x64 application.

Comment: You could check per-user registry, there is also `Uninstall` hive:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`